# Show that specific functions are correct for a race-free Moore machine

Tags: boolean-algebra, state-machines

Context: The goal here is to create a Latch that holds a state. We have two inputs x1, x2 and two outputs f1, f2. When (x1, x2) = (0, 1) or (x1, x2) = (1, 0) the outputs should be the same. When the input is (0, 0) the outputs should not change. For this, we need an asynchronous sequential circuit in Moore-form with two stable states (01, 10) in order to make the graph race-free we add a middle state (11).

We have a state transition graph in Moore-form:

[image]

The inputs are in the form of $$(x_1, x_2)$$
The output are the names of the state (Moore) and are named as $$(f_1, f_2)$$ and updated outputs $$({f^+}_1, {f^+}_2)$$
We are given two functions that describe f+ 1 and 2. They look as follows:

[image]

Now how do I show that the functions actually describe the graph above?

I started doing a truth-table for the graph it now looks like this:

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline f_1 & f_2 & x_1 & x_2 & {f^+}_1 & {f^+}_2 \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & - & 0 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & - & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline 0 & 1 & 0 & - & 0 & 1 \\ \hline  \end{array}$$
When looking at f1+ and f2+ we see that they're 0 2 times each. And both times do indeed correspond with the functions given to us.

But when writing out the boolean expression for f1+ I get this:
$${f^+}_1 = f_1f_2{x^´}_1x_2 \vee {f^´}_1f_2{x^´}_1x_2$$
With deMorgans distributive law we get
$${f^+}_1 = f_2{x^´}_1x_2(f_1 \vee {f^´}_1)$$
and since A´ V A is always = to 1 we get:
$${f^+}_1 = f_2{x^´}_1x_2$$

This is kinda similar to the original but x2 is present and it's not negated. What steps am I doing wrong here? Maybe it has to do with that x2 is a don't are and therefore should not be included? But what about the negating part?

Note:
This is what the graph looks like in gate-form. It basically is a standard bistable latch.

[image]

Update:
Okay, so thanks to jonk for providing with a good K-map. We get these prime implicants:

[image]

The resulting expressions are then:
$${f^+}_1 = {f´}_2 \vee x_1$$
$${f^+}_2 = {f´}_1 \vee x_2$$

when applying deMorgan we get the original expressions
$${f^+}_1 = ( {x^´}_1\wedge f_2)´$$
$${f^+}_2 = ( {x^´}_2\wedge f_1)´$$

Comment: You might get a better answer over on Mathematics SE.

Comment: Felix, what happens when in state \$\left(f_1,f_2\right)=\left(0,1\right)\$ and you get an excitation of \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\left(1,1\right)\$? I don't see anything for that in the diagram. Is there an assumption to be made here? Only three of the four possible input permutations are specified in the diagram for that state. Is it excluded? Similarly, for state \$\left(f_1,f_2\right)=\left(1,1\right)\$ is excitation \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\left(0,0\right)\$ also excluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Inserting my assumptions into your question

I'm going to assume that any \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)\$ inputs that are ***not*** shown on your diagram are ***illegal*** and cannot occur. So, for example, in state \$\left(f_1,f_2\right)=\left(0,1\right)\$ there is nothing shown for input \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\left(1,1\right)\$. So I'm assuming it cannot happen in that state. Therefore, it doesn't matter what is done should it happen, since it cannot happen.

I'm making similar assumptions for the other two states, as well.

### State table

In that case, I find the following table:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
\text{State} & \text{Inputs} & \text{Next State}\\\hline\\
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cccc}
  f_1 & f_2\\\\
  0&1\\
  0&1\\
  1&1\\
  1&1\\
  1&0\\
  1&0\\
  \\
  0&0\\
  0&1\\
  1&1\\
  1&1\\
  1&0
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{cc}
  x_1 & x_2\\\\
  \left.\begin{array}{c}
    0\\
    1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    x\\
    0\\
  \\
    x\\
    1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    1
  \end{array}  \right. &
  \left.\begin{array}{c}
    x\\
    0\\
    1\\
    0\\
    0\\
    1\\
  \\
    x\\
    1\\
    0\\
    1\\
    1
  \end{array}  \right.
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}} &
{\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{ccc}
  f_1^+ & f_2^+\\\\
  0&1\\
  1&1\\
  0&1\\
  1&0\\
  1&0\\
  1&1\\
  \\
  x&x\\
  x&x\\
  x&x\\
  x&x\\
  x&x
  \end{array}\end{smallmatrix}}
\end{array}$$

The bottom five rows are for those cases I mentioned at the outset -- the ***illegal*** input cases. The associated \$x\$'s showing for those rows just mean that it doesn't matter what happens then.

### Resulting K-Maps

These two are the resulting K-Maps:

$$\begin{array}{rl}
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
f_1^+&\overline{f_1}\:\overline{f_2}&\overline{f_1}\: f_2&f_1 \:f_2&f_1 \:\overline{f_2}\\
\hline
\overline{x_1}\:\overline{x_2}&x&0&x&1\\
\overline{x_1}\: x_2&x&0&0&1\\
\vphantom{x_1\:\overline{x_2}}x_1\: x_2&x&x&x&x\\
x_1\:\overline{x_2}&x&1&1&1
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
&
\begin{smallmatrix}\begin{array}{r|cccc}
f_2^+&\overline{f_1}\:\overline{f_2}&\overline{f_1}\: f_2&f_1 \:f_2&f_1 \:\overline{f_2}\\
\hline
\overline{x_1}\:\overline{x_2}&x&1&x&0\\
\overline{x_1}\: x_2&x&1&1&1\\
\vphantom{x_1\:\overline{x_2}}x_1\: x_2&x&x&x&x\\
x_1\:\overline{x_2}&x&1&0&0
\end{array}\end{smallmatrix}
\end{array}$$

What logic do you come up with for these?

And does any of this help you in making your proof?

### Summary

You cannot prove that your starting diagram is the only possible one from those two recurrence statements. You can show congruence. But you can't show it is the only possible one.

Some of the unspecified inputs, for example, might instead have been specified rather than left as illegal. And that would be a different diagram. Yet the same two logic statements. So I'm not sure what you want to demonstrate. You will need to be clearer about it, I think, if what I've provided isn't sufficient for your needs.

Just to make the point, here's a diagram that is ***also*** completely compatible with the two recurrences:

[image]

The above retains the idea that \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\left(1,1\right)\$ remains an input that doesn't occur. And the following one allows it:

[image]

The two statements are alone insufficient to produce a unique state diagram.

Even if you include the additional requirements that \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)\ne\left(1,1\right)\$ and \$\left(f_1,f_2\right)\ne\left(0,0\right)\$ then you still could have drawn this slightly different-looking diagram:

[image]

Which begs the question as to why the original diagram didn't look like that, assuming \$\left(x_1,x_2\right)=\left(0,0\right)\$ is a valid input, as it does include similar loops on the left-hand and right-hand diagram states.

Comment: I don't think two of the variables can change at the same time. They specify that we need an asynchronous sequential circuit with two stable states (01, 10) and they include the middle step in order to make it race-free.

Comment: @felix9801 That's new information that wasn't in your original question, so far as I noticed anyway. Even with this new information, your original diagram is missing some bits. Worse still, it violates what you just now wrote! For example, to get to state 11 from 01, (1,0) is used. Once in 11, though, a (0,1) can transition back to 01 state. This is a double-bit change. Which disagrees with what you just wrote. Or else I completely misunderstand you.

Comment: Also, the goal isn't to prove that the graph is the only solution. Only that the functions given do indeed describe the graph.

Comment: @jonk How did you make those state diagrams? Did you use some kind of software?

Comment: @Carl Just Windows' PAINT. Nothing more.